# How I can write to change a lot of variants and store my values from loop

Tags: programming, numerical-integration

If my function is

```
LUM[x1_, x2_] := Module[{l = x1, v = x2},
  T = (4*l*h*f)/(me*c^2);
  Tq = h*v/((l*me*c^2) - h*v);
  q = Tq/T;
  upper = q*f*4.0*l^2;
  lower = q*f;
  F = (2 q*Log[q] + (1 + 2 q) (1 - q) + ((Tq^2)*(1 - q))/(2*(1 + Tq)));
  n = (8*Pi*f^2/c^3)*((1/(Exp[h*f/(k*Tcmb)] - 1))
        + (Nsl/(Exp[h*f/(k*Tsl)] - 1))
        + (Nir/(Exp[h*f/(k*Tir)] - 1)));
  f = 10.0^uf;
  data = Table[{uf, F*n}, {uf, Log[10, lower], Log[10, upper], 0.05}];
  lum = Integrate[
    Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 2][uf],
    {uf, Log[10, lower], Log[10, upper] - 0.1}
   ]*Log[10]*(3*Th*c*h*v/(4*l^2));
  Clear[f];
  lum
]
```

and I want to change `x2` that have a lot of values and If I want to write loop to find `LUM`. How can I write and store value from `LUM`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Look up the documentation for `Table`.

Comment: Thank you,everyone for your help

Comment: Can I ark u more? after that I will do many thing and I wonder about store value from  loop by use 'for' . I find it on internet but it's not work for me. Can u write in by loop for example to me? I want it print by vector form e.g. {x2,LUM}

Comment: Some people just MUST use 'for' so you can modify this LUM[x_]:=Sin[x];Reap[For[x=1,x<5,x++,Sow[{x,LUM[x]}]]][[2,1]]

Comment: Thank you, Can I ask u something? In final parameter '[2,1]' What's it?

Comment: [[2]] extracts the second row from a matrix of results. [[2,1]] extracts the first column from the second row from a matrix of results. Try that code without the [[2,1]] and see the result. Then try that code with [[2]] and see the result. Then read the help page for Reap very carefully and click on Details to see more information on how it works. Then study how Table[[{x,LUM[x]},{x,1,4}] can do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the LUM function as written can't be used because it depends upon a number of global variables (h, me, k, Tcmd ...) that you have not supplied.

However, in order to produce a list of {x2, LUM[x1,x2]} pairs this can be done as follows.

**Scalar**

Assume x2List is the list of values that you want to evaluate and you want to evaluate LUM at a discrete (i.e., scalar) value for x1.

```
x2List = {1, 2, 3, ...}
```

Then one could use `Table`

```
Table[{x2, LUM[x1, x2]}, {x2, x2List}]
```

to produce the result.

Another approach would be to use `Map` with a pure function

```
Map[{#, Lum[x1, #]} &, x2List]
```

**Vector**

If you want to have the results be pairs of {x2, LUM[x1List, x2} where x1List is a list of x1 values (i.e, a vector) you do exactly the same operation except you set the attributes of LUM to be listable.

```
SetAttributes[LUM, Listable]
```

and then

```
 Table[{x2, LUM[x1List, x2]}, {x2, x2List}]
```

or

```
Map[{#, Lum[x1List, #]} &, x2List]
```